# Firebase/cloud firestore: onSnapshot() vs on()

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, listener

I have been using `onSnapshot` successfully to alert my code to changes in underlying data, as in

```
    //  Set up to listen for changes to the "figures" collection, that is,
    //  someone has created a new figure that we will want to list on the screen.

    setFiguresListener: function () {
        //  `figuresCR` is a collection reference defined elsewhere
        return this.figuresCR.onSnapshot((iFigs) => {
            iFigs.forEach((fSnap) => {
                const aFigure = figureConverter.fromFirestore(fSnap, null);
                const dbid = aFigure.guts.dbid;   //  ID of the "figure" in the database
                nos2.theFigures[dbid] = aFigure;  //  update the local copy of the data
            });
            nos2.ui.update();
            console.log(`   Listener gets ${iFigs.size} figures`);
        });
```

But I now read about `on` [in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#on). It explains:

> [The `on()` function] Listens for data changes at a particular location.

> *This is the primary way to read data from a Database*. Your callback
> will be triggered for the initial data and again whenever the data
> changes. Use `off( )`to stop receiving updates. See [Retrieve Data on
> the Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/retrieve-data) for more details.

The syntax is a bit different, and `on()` seems to do much the same as `onSnapshot()`.

So what is the real difference? Should we be using `on()` instead of `onSnapshot()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`on()` is an operation for reading from  Firebase Realtime Database.  That's a completely different database with different APIs than Firestore.  They have essentially no overlap.  There is no `on()` operation with Firestore.

If you're working with Firestore, ignore all the documentation about Realtime Database, and stick to using `onSnapshot()` for getting realtime updates.

Answer (score 0):

Other tyros who fall into this tar pit: in the API doc pages, you might *think* that since firestore is a database under firebase, you could look for help under `firebase.database`. But no: look only in the *next* section, `firebase.firestore`.

[image]